# For every partition of $E(K_{n,n})$ into $n$ colour classes of size $n$, there is a vertex incident to at least $\sqrt{n}$ colours

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, bipartite-graphs, probabilistic-method

Given a partition of the edges of $K_{n,n}$ into $n$ colours, where each colour appears exactly $n$ times, prove that there exists a vertex incident to at least $\sqrt{n}$ colours.

Comment: As it's now, this sounds as a misunderstanding. Every vertex of $\ K_{n\,n}\ $ is an end of $\ n\ $ different edges that are of $n$-different colors (by the definition of the edge-coloring).

Comment: Its not a proper edge colouring

Comment: Would you provide the definition of *proper edge coloring* (straight in your *Question*)? -- it'd be so nice.

Comment: Sorry I had missed an important detail, is it more clear now?

Comment: @WlodAA Proper edge colouring = edge colouring. Based on the discussion, I assume what the OP means is that we are given a labelling of edges by colours without any constraints on incident edges.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you. Thus "*coloring*" here seems simply an arbitrary labeling. After an Edit of OP Question, now this labeling is somewhat constrained.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short proof. Thanks to David Speyer for simplifying an earlier proof of mine (see the comments below).

For each colour $i \in [n]$, let $a_i$ be the number of vertices incident to an edge of colour $i$.  Observe that $a_i \geq 2\sqrt{n}$ for all $i$, where equality is obtained if and only if the edges of colour $i$ induce a $K_{\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n}}$.  Thus, $\sum_{i \in [n]} a_i \geq 2n \sqrt{n}$.  On the other hand, $\sum_{i \in [n]} a_i$ is the number of ordered pairs $(v,i)$, where $v$ is a vertex, and $i$ is a colour incident to $v$.  Therefore, since there are only $2n$ vertices, some vertex must be incident to at least $\sqrt{n}$ colours.

Comment: It seems like, after your key observation $\ell_i + r_i \geq 2 \sqrt{n}$, we can finish much faster than that. Note that $\sum \ell_i + \sum r_i$ is the number of ordered pairs $(v,c)$ where $v$ is a vertex and $i$ is a color incident to $i$. From $\ell_i + r_i \geq 2 \sqrt{n}$, we deduce that $\sum \ell_i + \sum r_i \geq 2n \sqrt{n}$. There are $2n$ options for $v$, so there is some $v$ incident to $\geq \sqrt{n}$ colors.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That's nice!  Thanks.  We can make the proof even slightly shorter by just defining $v_i$ to be the number of vertices incident to color $i$.  Then $v_i \geq 2\sqrt{n}$ for each colour $i$.